# How to make the marker smaller in legend in when plot with matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

In this figure, the marker in the legend is so big, how can I make it shorter.

I spend a lot of time searching for the solution online. But I did not find any solution that can fix this problem.

Thanks.

[image]

This is the code,

```
latency = [1 1.3 0.5;...
           0.8 1.2 0.4;...
           0.7 1.1 0.35;...
           0.9 1.0 0.3;...
           0.8 1.2 0.4;...
           0.7 1.1 0.3];
h = bar(latency);
set(h(1), 'FaceColor',[33 36 61]./255)
set(h(2), 'FaceColor',[240 240 240]./255)
set(h(3), 'FaceColor',[250 128 114]./255)
set(h, 'LineWidth', 1);
set(gca,'Linewidth',1,'Fontname', 'arial');
set(gca, 'XLim', [0, size(latency,1)+1])
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 max(max(latency))*1.1]);
xlabel('(a) Latency','FontSize',14)
ylabel('Latency (us)','FontSize',14)
legend({'AAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCC'}, 'Orientation', 'horizontal','FontSize',11)
box on;
```

Update:

According to the answer, I add two lines of codes:

```
[lgd,icons,plots,txt] = legend({'AAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCC'});
icons(4).Children.XData = icons(4).Children.XData/2;
```

Now I get this legend.

But there is a blank space before text.

[image]

Comment: I updated the question, adding code. The problem is how to change the marker size in legend.

Comment: Try `[lgd,icons,plots,txt] = legend({'AAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCC'}, 'Orientation', 'horizontal','FontSize',11);`. Then, `icons` contains the actual objects in the legend. For example, `icons(4)` is an `Annotation` and has a chlid of type `patch` that is the first coloured rectangle. You can manually do something like `icons(4).Children.XData = icons(4).Children.XData/2` to change its position and size

Comment: Using this code, the marker did become shorter. But the text ('AAAAAA') still stay at the same position as before. It does not adjust its position automatically. So there is a blank space between the marker and text.

Answer (score 1):

There is an **undocumented** propertie `ItemTokenSize` to do that:

```
% Fixe the new size of each box:
box_size = [10 10 10]

% Get the handle
hdl = legend({'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'})

% Set the new size
hdl.ItemTokenSize = box_size;

% Then recenter the legend
% ...
```

[image]

Undocumented means that this option could be deleted, without notice, in a future release.